# How to sink MessagePack-encoded messages into MongoDB from Kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, msgpack, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have a Kafka topic where the values are MessagePack-encoded.

Is there any way to sink the records from this topic into MongoDB using the MongoDB Kafka connector, or must the record values simply be stored as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find or create your own Kafka Connect [`Converter`](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/Converter.html), then add that package to each Connect worker's classpath, followed by setting it as your key/value converter setting, from which the existing Mongo Sink Connector can deserialize the messages into a `Struct` and `Schema` form, and handle correctly.

JSON was never a requirement. Avro and Protobuf should work as well